# How to disable in Seam Validation in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse

When I save every file, `Seam Validation` check the project. I am waiting for finished validation. I would like to disable this validation. I don't know where is it exist to configure in IDE. Could you provide the way?

Answer (score 0):

It should be available in the properties of your project under Validation.  (Click the project in your Package Explorer, then Project > Properties on the main menu and look for Validation in the left-hand pane of the Project Properties dialog.)